# concancatinating string unable to write into text file

Tags: dos, batch-file

I've a batch file in that I'm passing a command line argument and concatenating this argument with some string as bellow. suppose if i sent 1.0 as command line argument

```
echo ^<em:version^>%1^</em:version^>
```

this prints `<em:version>1.0</em:version>` and works fine.
if i tried to redirect this string to some text file using :

```
echo ^<em:version^>%1^</em:version^> >> test.txt
```

it written only `<em:version></em:version>` into file leaving the command line argument.
i wanted to write whole string with command line. 
What would be the problem ? how to fix this ?

Answer (score 5):

It works fine for me. I called it `1.bat`. I call it below:

```
d:\Uploads\fbi>1 1.0

d:\Uploads\fbi>echo <em:version>1.0</em:version>  1>>test.txt

d:\Uploads\fbi>type test.txt
<em:version>1.0</em:version>
```

Works with or without an `@echo off` up top.

What code is it in? Show us the code that calls it. Are you **SURE** that you are passing it a value?

Whatever variable you are passing it, echo that variable then pause it right before you call it like so:

```
echo %var%
pause
call 1.bat %var%
```

If all you get is:

```
ECHO is off.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Then the variable is empty.

Comment: hey i need following requirement :1.bat 5.7.8


<em:version> %1 <em:version> >> test.txt

i should get:
<em:version> 5.7.8 <em:version> in the test.txt file

But its not happening here

Comment: @user1668527 - What are you getting instead?

Comment: @user1668527, This is very odd. If your batch file is `echo ^<em:version^>%1^</em:version^> >>test.txt`, then typing `1.bat 5.7.8` should fill `test.txt` with `<em:version>5.7.8</em:version>`. I don't know what else to tell you.